# Tensorflow / Keras gradients return a None value in multi-task model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

When trying to train a multi-task model in Tensorflow using Keras, I run into the error of finding gradients whose values are None. When I use the regular `model.fit()`, I am able to train normally (without any issues) but Tensorboard shows some missing distributions (some of them are totally missing), which makes me believe something is going on with gradients.
[image: Missing data]

Then, when I try to debug this using a custom training loop, I see gradient values coming out as None. For ex, like this:

```
w1 = tf.Variable(1.0)
w2 = tf.Variable(1.0)    
for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(trainDS):
                    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                        logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
                        
                        loss1 = loss_fn1(y_batch_train['label1'], logits[0])
                        loss2 = loss_fn2(y_batch_train['label2'], logits[1])
                        l1 = tf.math.multiply(w1, loss1)
                        l2 = tf.math.multiply(w2, loss2)
                        loss_value = tf.math.add(l1, l2)

                    grad_task_1 = tape.gradient(l1, model.trainable_weights)
```

I get gradients of None when inspecting the list.
Eventually I want to compute the normm of grad_task_1 gradients, but cannot do that with Nones.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong from an approach POV or from a design POV?
Or am I missing something?
Could anyone kindly provide some guidance. Would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you want to consider what is the gradient/derivative of a constant.

Comment: Even without the tf.constant() wrap for l1, I get None gradients

Comment: Sure but we only can answer for what is on the question, not something else.

Comment: Have updated the question, to reflect no tf.constant call.
Do you have a solution to this in this case?

Comment: No, the content between the plots does not have a direct relationship with your code, you need to clarify that, even mention what list you are talking about (when inspecting the list).

Comment: The plots represent convolution kernels in my model that have missing data, which I assume to be because of missing gradients (not sure). Unfortunately, I cannot explicitly provide the code for the model because it is part of a research project. 
The list I am talking about is grad_task_1 , which is a list of all the gradients for the model weights